# Automatically expand TreeView to specific node

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, nodes, expand

I already got a working code, though the application can only go through "small" directories, otherwise it gets stuck and the RAM usage keeps going up.

I need a different method for an automatic expandation of folders/paths which contain files with specific extensions (their Header contains a CheckBox).

Here's what I got:

```
private void JumpToNode(ItemCollection collection)
    {
        foreach (var nodename in filesFound)
        {
            if (!nodename.StartsWith("$"))
            {
                foreach (var item in collection)
                {
                    var tvi = (TreeViewItem)item;

                    if (tvi.Header is System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)
                    {
                        var cb = (System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)tvi.Header;

                        if (cb.Content.ToString() == nodename)
                        {
                            tvi.IsExpanded = true;
                            tvi.BringIntoView();
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    if (tvi.HasItems)
                    {
                        JumpToNode(tvi.Items);
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: At first glance, your recursion seems wrong.  Every time you call JumpToNode(tvi.Items), you are starting from the beginning of filesFound again.

Comment: @user2880486 Thanks a lot, I would've never thought that way in the near future. I changed the order of the loops and now it runs pretty smooth.